# ERROR LARAVEL CORREO: Unable to connect with STARTTLS: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1

Tags: php, laravel, web, smtp

Saludos a la cumunidad!

Recientemente he desarrollado una página web con **Laravel 9.X**, la cual funciona correctamente en local, pero a la hora de subirla a mi Host, estoy teniendo problemas con el envío de correos electrónicos.

Cuando he estado haciendo pruebas en local, me ha funcionado correctamente, y he utilizado **mailtrap**. Ahora que lo he subido al servidor, tengo mi propio SMTP, y no me funciona. Tengo creado el certificado **ssl**, pero no hay manera de que me mande ningún correo. Me da el siguiente error:

*Unable to connect with STARTTLS: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed*

He configurado mi fichero `.env`, donde le he puesto:

`HOST`: mi servidor smtp; `PUERTO`: 587;  `TIPO ENCRIPTACIÓN`: SSL; `USUARIO Y CONTRASEÑA`: Las de mi cuenta de correo.

He estado tocando también mi fichero que se encuentra en `config/mail.php`, poniendo la misma configuración que en el fichero `.env`. También he probado con otros puertos como el 25, 465.. entre otros.

He intentado acceder a la cuenta de correo desde **outlook**, utilizando el protocolo `IMAP`, y me he conseguido conectar correctamente, por lo que al correo se puede acceder.

¿Alguna idea sobre que me puede estar pasando?
¿Me falta algo por configurar?

Comment: Ahora muchos correos incluyendo outlook utilizan las contraseñas de aplicaciones, donde no necesitas colocar tu contraseña actual del correo, verifica eso

Comment: A que te refieres con eso? Ya he conseguido acceder desde el Outlook, por lo que imagino que el correo está bien configurado, el problema debe de estar en mi configuración pienso yo.

Comment: Aveces son varios factores, casi siempre son por el servidor de correos, no necesariamente tu configuración, puede ser debido a una configuración general con los servidores, aveces puede ser por ciertos accesos, peroooo actualmente para poder utilizar outlook para enviar correos ellos solicitan una "contraseña de servicios o programas" no recuerdo bien el nombre, donde simplemente se genera un codigo según lo que solicites y esa clave debes ponerla en los acceso smtp, para que no coloques tu contraseña actual del correo

Comment: Consigo conectar la cuenta en Outlook, y hacer que envíe y reciba correos desde el Outlook. Lo que no consigo hacer es que funcione desde el servidor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para solucionar este problema, en Laravel 9.X, hay que añadir `'verify_peer' => false`, al igual que en otras versiones, pero en este caso hay que añadirlo en un sitio distinto. Dentro de mi fichero `config/mail.php` y dentro de `smtp`:

```
'mailers' => [
         'smtp' => [
             'transport' => 'smtp',
             'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'localhost'),
             'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 25),
             'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
             'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
             'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
             'timeout' => null,

             'verify_peer' => false,
         ],
```